# How to get values from array in Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have an Array
`@Binding var classificationInProcent: Array<Any>` to which I assigned the values from `let classificationTest = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]`. When I used `print(type(Of: classificationTest))` I get that is an Array

Now in `classificationInProcent` I have values:

`[(confidence: 0.8427822, identifier: "Rose"), (confidence: 0.15579186, identifier: "Carnation"), (confidence: 0.00085995096, identifier: "Tulip"), (confidence: 0.00027763256, identifier: "Magnolia"), (confidence: 0.00016394019, identifier: "Poppy"), (confidence: 0.00010621416, identifier: "Daisy"), (confidence: 1.5651864e-05, identifier: "Orchid"), (confidence: 1.4234058e-06, identifier: "Hyacinth"), (confidence: 1.0996952e-06, identifier: "Sunflower"), (confidence: 3.0659162e-08, identifier: "Iris")]`
I would like to extract each value separately, that's `confidence: 0.8427822`, `identifier: "Rose"` separately. I need this values, because I will create charts and use it there.
I've tried to print values from `classificationInProcent` in this way:
`print("First value: ", classificationInProcent[0].confidence)` but Xcode shows me that after dot i cannot use confidence, just `self`.

How can I get all these values from Array?

Comment: Why have you made this an array of Any? It is an array of `(Double, String)`. And why is it a `@Binding`? Is this actually a SwiftUI question? In that case, show more context please.

Comment: Hi @matt thank you for your answer. I edited a bit my post.

Comment: "When I used print(type(Of: classificationTest)) I get that is an Array" But it is not an array of Any. It is an array of VNClassificationObservation.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `classificationInProcent` is already inferred from its value and you don't need to give it as I've show in the code below, also why not just simply loop over the `classificationInProcent` using a `forEach`.

```
let classificationInProcent = [(confidence: 0.8427822, identifier: "Rose"), (confidence: 0.15579186, identifier: "Carnation"), (confidence: 0.00085995096, identifier: "Tulip"), (confidence: 0.00027763256, identifier: "Magnolia"), (confidence: 0.00016394019, identifier: "Poppy"), (confidence: 0.00010621416, identifier: "Daisy"), (confidence: 1.5651864e-05, identifier: "Orchid"), (confidence: 1.4234058e-06, identifier: "Hyacinth"), (confidence: 1.0996952e-06, identifier: "Sunflower"), (confidence: 3.0659162e-08, identifier: "Iris")]

classificationInProcent.forEach { (confidence, identifier) in
    print("First value: ", confidence)
    print("Second value: ", identifier)
}
```